# Time when OnTriggerEnter is called lacks precision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this weird situation where I'm trying to compute the exact time in milliseconds when a cursor enters a trigger area in Unity.

Whenever I try to compute the time inside the OnTriggerEnter method, I only have 2 numbers after the decimal point.

If I compute the time with Time.time in the void Start() method, I get 6 numbers after the decimal point.

I am trying to compute the reaction time by subtracting "start_time" to "trigger_ms" but because of this weird rounding up - the result makes no sense.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
 void Start()
{
    float start_time = Time.time;
    Debug.Log($"{start_time} seconds");
}
```

This outputs like "8.256458 seconds".

But this outputs, for example, "8.25 seconds" :

```
     void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Cursor"))
    {
        float trigger_ms = Time.time;
        Debug.Log($"{trigger_ms} seconds");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand what exactly you are trying to achieve by that but in general the physics update is based on a fixed time interval configured in the Physics settings or via [`Time.fixedDeltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html) while `Start` and `Update` happen within the normal frame rate interval which is not a fixed value but will vary depending on the things you do within each frame (`Time.deltaTime`). See also [Time Management](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/TimeFrameManagement.html)

---

You could just use [`DateTime.Now`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now) instead which gives you the systems time based on ticks in that instance of time and then use the delta between the two values which gives you a [`TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timespan). Then you can read out e.g. [`TotalMilliseconds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds#system-timespan-totalmilliseconds)

---

Alternatively you could also use a [`StopWatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch), which is also based on the system ticks, [`Start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.start#system-diagnostics-stopwatch-start) it and then [`Stop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.stop#system-diagnostics-stopwatch-stop) it and read out [`ElapsedMilliseconds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedmilliseconds#system-diagnostics-stopwatch-elapsedmilliseconds)

Comment: Oh that helps a lot - timing in Unity is still a bit obscure to me. I was trying to get the reaction time of the moment the player enters the trigger area and I tried 2 other ways that you suggested with success (get Unix TimeStamp at start and when the OnTriggerMethod is called ; or using a Stopwatch). I appreciate the help and explanation !

Answer (score 0):

You don't need extra digits due to the physically limited resolution of the timer. It's about 15 ms in Windows systems.